# Problema al publicar sitio web en visual studio community 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, .net, microsoft

Buenas Busco su apoyo para dar con la solución al error obtenido  al publicar una web. Ya limpie la solución re-compile, ejecuto VS como administrador pero sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje de error.

El error es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comprobé la ventana de salida de actividad de publicación, como dice el mensaje y me sale lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho el apoyo para dar solución al inconveniente, saludos.

Comment: Hay quienes desean ayudarte y para ello, aquí unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 luego edita la pregunta agregando todo lo que sea necesario para reproducir tu escenario. Saludos.

Comment: Tenes que fijarte en la ventana de Lista de Errores que se encuentra en la parte inferior de VS
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekyy5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekyy5.png)